# CurlException when trying to use copyObject with Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, curl

I'm trying to copy a file I've already placed in an S3 bucket. When I try to perform the copy I get the following error:

> Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException
>
> [curl] 56: SSL read: error:1408F119:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0
>   [url] (url omitted by me)

Any idea what is causing this error? I'm able to use the `putObject` command with no problems and I've checked that the file exists (both looking at the bucket and by using the `doesObjectExist` command.

```
        $response = $this->client->copyObject(array(
                "ACL" => "public-read",
                "Bucket" => Yii::app()->params['S3Bucket'],
                "CopySource" => Yii::app()->params['S3BucketFolder'] . $old_key,
                "Key" => Yii::app()->params['S3BucketFolder'] . $key,
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The `CopySource` parameter requires the bucket as part of it. I was trying to copy files in the same bucket so this wasn't apparent to me but once I reread the documentation I realized my mistake.

So the line should be:

```
"CopySource" => Yii::app()->params['S3Bucket'] . '/' . Yii::app()->params['S3BucketFolder'] . $old_key,
```